# AJAX Same Origin Policy issues with 3rd party API on p2p network

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, post, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a HTML5 webapp to be used in controlling a 3rd party robotic device that has a TXAS XML API Web Service used for accepting commands.  I have no access to change the 3rd Party API, and it is very basic.  It has a structured XML command format with basic authorization and it doesn't understand JSON or JSONP, just straight XML.

I am trying to write this as elegantly as possible and have the app completely self-contained in the file to be loaded onto the control device (tablet/smartphone) without need of any interaction with a remote server after it has been loaded. i.e. this will be a p2p application between the tablet and the device it's controlling.

I think immediately I am running into the S.O.P. limitation which is causing problems but I'm not sure how to get around it since the code is local to the tablet and the device I'm controlling is not.

Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
function postXML(strIN){            
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "http://1.1.1.1/putxml",
        contentType: "text/xml",
        datatype: "xml",
        data: strIN,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr){ xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic " + btoa("user:pass")); },
        error: function(request, error) { alert("error:" + error);}
        }); 
    }
$("#preset1").click(function(){
    var str = '<Command><Preset><Activate><PresetId>1</PresetId></Activate></Preset></Command>';
    postXML(str);
    });
```

The code executes clean in safari when launched from the local drive; however, it will not work with chrome, firefox, or IE when launched in the same manner (triggers the error event).

Being that most of the devices that will be using this are iPhones/ipads I didn't think this to be a big deal, but, my method of loading the page onto the device is via HTTP and then to save locally.  When done in this manner it also fails on safari as well.  I've used a diff-merge program to verify that the HTTP loaded code and the locally sourced code are identical and they are, but for some reason the HTTP loaded code will not execute (triggers the error event).

Am I hitting the S.O.P. limitation here?  I've looked for possible ways around this but they all seem to require an external server or proxy which is not an option for my deployment scenario.

I should also note that I am not expecting anything back from the device, nor do I require to have any other interaction with it apart from just POST'ing XML to it's webservice.

Some additional debug data from Chrome:

```
Failed to load resource: Resource failed to load http://1.1.1.1/putxml

OPTIONS http://1.1.1.1/putxml Resource failed to load jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
send                  jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.extend.ajax         jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
postXML               index-working.html:35
(anonymous function)  index-working.html:53
p.event.dispatch      jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
g.handle.h            jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
```

Comment: Are you building a web-app, native app? Or hybrid app?

Comment: Also, what error event is being triggered in most browsers?

Comment: It's a web-app that's delivered via HTTP, but then meant to be saved locally to the tablet/smartphone and run autonomously from there.  It requires not additional interaction with the HTTP server after it's been loaded to the device.  All of the code in the page is targeting the p2p networked client (in the example above 1.1.1.1 is the p2p client.

Comment: The error event triggered is the one defined in the call. error: function(requets, error) { alert("error:" + error);}); In the case above, an alert dialog that says "error:error". In otherwords, the browser is responding to the error event with data of "error"

Comment: What happens when you visit `http://1.1.1.1/putxml` directly in your browser?

Comment: If I go there directly I'm issuing a GET when it's expecting a POST.  It asks for credentials and upon entering them it presents me with a page that says "XML syntax error: none" as in, I didn't provide it any XML.  Remember, it's working fine when I call it via file://index-working.html and load it from my HD via Safari.  It's just failing everywhere else. Loading it via HTTP from anywhere fails, and loading it via file:// fails on IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  I'm guessing there's something wrong with the code that Safari is just ignoring and everything is properly treating as an error.

Comment: I think the http:// vs file:// discrepancy might be your problem. What happens if you server it over http in FF? total error?

Comment: IE, FF, and Chrome behave the same via either file:// or http:// (fail). Safari is the only one that behaves differently.  Safari works with file:// and fails with same result as IE, FF, or Chrome via http://

Comment: So, it's definately an S-O-P issue.  I put a reverse proxy in place and it executes clean across all browsers.  Problem is, since the app is meant for a p2p network, there will be no servers available to run a reverse proxy from.  I'm guessing there's just not option for using ajax to post content to an external server which you don't have access to establish a CORS relationship with.  Funny how Safari ignores S-O-P when executing code from a local drive.

Comment: While odd, I think it actually makes sense, considering a post or get located locally can't be you being malicious.

Comment: If its a native or hybrid app, you should perform the post without running into SOP. Simply use the native to js bridge and execute from there.